# Sign jar files with a Microsoft Authenticode Certificate

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-signing

Can I use Microsoft Authenticode Certificate for java code signing? Does anyone have experience with it?

I found [this tutorial](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO133&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1393582392293) on the website of Thawte, which describes how to convert MS Certificate to Java one. On the other side Thawte sells java code signing certificates and I'm not sure if there are some cons converting the MS one.

P.S: I want to sign eclipse plugins with it.

Comment: You should somehow get a `*.p12` file (password-protected) from your Authenticode certificate. Then you should execute `jarsigner` to sign a jar:
`jarsigner -keystore <path-to-p12-file> -storetype pkcs12 -storepass <password> -tsa http://tsa.starfieldtech.com -verbose <jar-name> <alias>` (the alias can be found by running `keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore <path-to-p12-file>`)

Comment: @orionll: The tutorial describes how to get the .p12 file, but do you know if there is a difference between java code signing certificate and the Microsoft Authenticode Certificate? Or it is just the certificate format?

Comment: There is no difference, I think. However, Windows and Java use different trusted stores. You should check that your certificate provider is in the trusted authorities list. You can check it by executing `keytool -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -list`

Comment: I'm using thawte and they are supported. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use keytool provided by jdk for generating the certificate, you can sign your jar file with this certificate by using the jarsigner tool. Both keytool, jarsigner are available in bin folder of the jdk1.7.0 kit.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html

Comment: For test purposes I've tried that, but it still shows a warning in eclipse, that the certificate is not trusted.

Comment: Run `jarsigner -verify <your-jar>`. Is the jar actually signed?

Answer (score 1):

There is typically no difference between a certificate for Authenticode or Java code signing. Both are X.509 certificates with the Extended Key Usage (EKU) "Code Signing".

What could be different is the format of the key store. That is how the private key together with the certificate is stored (if stored in software and not on a smartcard or in a hardware security module). Historically Java was using the Java Keystore format (JKS) but can nowdays use PKCS#12/PFX as well. You should be able to convert the keystore to an appropriate format.